# bower ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH, como resolver?

Tags: angularjs, front-end, bower

eu estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação na qual pretendo usar a framework AngularJS. Para baixar as dependências do front-end eu estou usando o Bower, no entanto quando eu escrevo o comando no CMD para que eu faça a instalação:

```
bower install angularjs --save
```

Está me retornando essa seguinte mensagem:

```
bower ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o porque disso? Lembrando que instalei o GIT em minha máquina, precisa fazer algum tipo de configuração? Ficarei grato se puderem me ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quem passar pelo mesmo problema que eu, descobri a causa e é muito simples, isso ocorre devido ao fato de você não possuir o GIT instalado, eu tinha instalado na minha máquina, portanto fiz a instalação com o servidor aberto, tive que reiniciar o server, após fazer isso eu consegui!